# selection from dropdown one, remove select options based on value from dropdown one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

We use drop downs with content to choose an airport and its terminal, then another drop down to choose the service inside that airport and terminal. for example airport 1 and international terminal. Some airport and terminals now have no services included. When that airport and terminal are selected then select options should be removed and offered with no services etc or something on those lines

EDITED CODE SO FAR

```
//form one
<select class="req input-disabled" name="ddlairport_terminal" id="ddlairport_terminal">
    <option value="">Airport terminal</option>
    <option value="92|138">Suvarnabhumi International</option>
    <option value="92|135">Suvarnabhumi Domestic</option>
    <option value="93|138">Don Mueang International</option>
    <option value="93|135">Don Mueang Domestic</option>
</select>

<select class="req input-disabled" name="ddltransit" id="ddltransit">
    <option value="">Choose a service</option>
</select>

//form 2
<select class="req input-disabled" id="ret_ddlairport_terminal" name="ret_ddlairport_terminal">
    <option value="">Airport terminal</option>
    <option value="92|138">Suvarnabhumi international</option>
    <option value="92|135">Suvarnabhumi domestic</option>
    <option value="93|138">Don muang international</option>
    <option value="93|135">Don muang domestic</option>
</select>

<select class="req input-disabled" name="ret_ddltransit" id="ret_ddltransit">
    <option value="">Choose a service</option>
</select>
```

And here is my javascript

```
// airport service tab
var allservices = '<option value="">Choose a service</option><option value="110">Arrival</option><option value="111">Departure</option><option value="Gate to gate">Gate to gate (Transit)</option>';
var partialserviceairports = ["93|135","93|138"];
var airportservicemapping = {"93|135":["110","Gate to gate"],"93|138":["110","Gate to gate"]};
var servicenamemapping = {"110":"Arrival","111":"Departure","Gate to gate": "Gate to gate (Transit)"};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#ddlairport_terminal").on('change',function(){
        var selectedval = $(this).val();
        var servieces = "";
        if(!selectedval || partialserviceairports.indexOf(selectedval)>-1)
        {
            $("select#ddltransit").html(getOptions(selectedval));
        }
        else
        {
            $("select#ddltransit").html(allservices);
        }

    });
    $("select#ret_ddlairport_terminal").on('change',function(){
        var selectedval = $(this).val();
        var servieces = "";
        if(!selectedval || partialserviceairports.indexOf(selectedval)>-1)
        {
            $("select#ret_ddltransit").html(getOptions(selectedval));
        }
        else
        {
            $("select#ret_ddltransit").html(allservices);
        }

    });

    function getOptions(airportvalue)
    {
        var options = airportservicemapping[airportvalue];
        var optionshtml = "";
        for(var value in options)
        {
            var key = options[value];
            optionshtml += '<option value="'+key+'">'+servicenamemapping[key]+'</option>';
        }
        optionshtml = '<option value="">Choose a service</option>' + optionshtml;
        return optionshtml;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you maybe looking for.

```js
var partialserviceairports = ["93|135","93|138"];
var airportservicemapping = {"93|135":["110","Gate to gate"],"93|138":["110","Gate to gate"]};
var servicenamemapping = {"110":"Arrival","111":"Departure","Gate to gate": "Gate to gate"};
var disabledoptions = {"ret_ddltransit":["Gate to gate"]};

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#ddlairport_terminal").on('change',function(){
        var selectedval = $(this).val();
        var servieces = "";
        if(!selectedval || partialserviceairports.indexOf(selectedval)>-1)
        {
            $("select#ddltransit").html(getOptions(selectedval));
        }
        else
        {
            $("select#ddltransit").html(getAllServices());
        }

    });
    
    $("select#ret_ddlairport_terminal").on('change',function(){
        var selectedval = $(this).val();
        var servieces = "";
        if(!selectedval || partialserviceairports.indexOf(selectedval)>-1)
        {
            $("select#ret_ddltransit").html(getOptions(selectedval,"ret_ddltransit"));
        }
        else
        {
            $("select#ret_ddltransit").html(getAllServices());
        }

    });
    
    function getAllServices()
    {
        var services = "";
        for(var key in servicenamemapping)
        {
            services += '<option value="'+key+'">'+servicenamemapping[key]+'</option>';
        }
        services = '<option value="">Choose a service</option>' + services;
        return services;
    }
    
    function getOptions(airportvalue,selectid)
    {
        var options = airportservicemapping[airportvalue];
        var optionshtml = "";
        for(var value in options)
        {
            var key = options[value];
            optionshtml += '<option value="'+key+'"';
            if(selectid && disabledoptions[selectid] && disabledoptions[selectid].indexOf(key)>-1)
            {
                optionshtml += 'disabled';
            }
            optionshtml+='>'+servicenamemapping[key]+'</option>';
        }
        optionshtml = '<option value="">Choose a service</option>' + optionshtml;
        return optionshtml;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="req input-disabled" id=ddlairport_terminal name="ddlairport_terminal">
 <option value="">Airport terminal</option>
 <option value="92|138">Suvarnabhumi international</option>
 <option value="92|135">Suvarnabhumi domestic</option>
 <option value="93|138">Don muang international</option>
 <option value="93|135">Don muang domestic</option>
 <option value="94|138">Chennai international</option>
 <option value="94|135">Chennai domestic</option>
</select>


<select class="req input-disabled" name="ddltransit" id="ddltransit">
    <option value="">Choose a service</option>
</select>

<select class="req input-disabled" id="ret_ddlairport_terminal" name="ret_ddlairport_terminal">
    <option value="">Airport terminal</option>
    <option value="92|138">Suvarnabhumi international</option>
    <option value="92|135">Suvarnabhumi domestic</option>
    <option value="93|138">Don muang international</option>
    <option value="93|135">Don muang domestic</option>
</select>

<select class="req input-disabled" name="ret_ddltransit" id="ret_ddltransit">
    <option value="">Choose a service</option>
</select>
```

Comment: definitely on the correct track. The problem is that its only Don muang domestic -> departure that has no services. Not the airport and terminal. So i need to find a way to not show the departure in the dropdown when  Don muang domestic has been clicked on

Comment: You mean on selecting Don muang domestic in select1 and departure in select2 should display `No services` right ?

Comment: Yeah, when I click on the don mueang domestic then we should be seeing on the select 2 only arrival and g2g. Using something like this var limitedservies = '<option value="">Choose a service</option><option value="110">Arrival</option><option value="Gate to gate">Gate to gate</option>';

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it suits the case you asked for.

Comment: Wanting to add "93|135" and "93|138" to be the same, both dont have services.

Comment: I didn’t get you

Comment: `var partialserviceairports = ["93|135"] || ["93|138"];
var airportservicemapping = {"93|135" || {"93|138":["110","Gate to gate"]};` something like this. so don m inter and dom both have no departure services. sorry for confusion

Comment: Sorry. Went for lunch. Now updated the answer. You just need to add the services needed to the array.

Comment: How would I go about not showing any gate to gate services on `select#ret_ddlairport_terminal` so gate to gate is only an option allowed on the first select `select#ddlairport_terminal`

Comment: Cant get you clearly. As I have given answer for only 1 select. And you are asking for two selects. Have you modified any of your requirement ?

Comment: Added edited code. I just need on the second form to only show arrival on select 2. At the moment I have copied and pasted the script originally made and removed the gate to gate for select 2

Comment: You mean, in form 2 whatever selected in select 1, only arrival option should be displayed in the select 2 , right?

Comment: the same as the select 1, but no gate to gate option  should be able to be selected

Comment: @hputtick Updated the answer. Hope I made the requirement. Also it seems you are using the first answer. Shall I remove the second one? Because I feel a bit annoying to modify both answers when you ask for a change.

Comment: sure whatever you fell most comfortable with :)

Comment: whats the procedure of adding all aiports and terminals to not have gate to gate on the return select (form 2). At the moment its just don muang, I need suvaranbhumi both terminals gate to gate on return to be the same as don muang return as disabled.